# Run X app without a window

Tags: xorg, window

Is it possible to run a program that usually displays a window without showing one?  I want to run empathy in gnome shell but if I exit the app, it kills the process.

Comment: Not quite get your meaning..

Comment: basically I want a way to make an arbitrary application run without opening a window.

Comment: Arbitrary app?  I don't think so. Maybe kill the X server but then some apps will exit because it is considered (and justifiably so) an unrecoverable error.  Why can't you just minimize the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
~ $ Xvfb :1 &
~ $ DISPLAY=:1 empathy &
~ $ ps
```

If everything went as expected, you should now see a process listing containing your empathy process.

Note: I don't have Gnome or empathy available on any boxes right now, so I don't know how well empathy likes being in a vfb. Works splendidly for xdvi, though.

Comment: Possible that this works, i couldn't figure out how to get xvfb, i did `apt-get install xvfb` on Mint, but it still said command not found. Oh well, in the time between asking this question and now this has become far less important to me, perhaps because I have less school work that I should be doing.

Comment: Pardon my misspelling, the X in Xvfb should be uppercase.